# Selecting from the same table with result of table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to select a row and use values from that row in a query.

Something like, select * from users where id = 1, select * from users where id !=1 and permission = user with id 1's permission

So I want to get a user with the id of 1, then select all other rows from the same table that are not of id 1 and have the same permission as id 1. I don;t know the permission until I select the first row.

Is this possible in eloquent in one query?

Comment: User::whereNotIn('id', 1)->where('permission', '=', User::find(1)->permission)->get();

Comment: The user has relation with permission table or user table have one column permission ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a subquery like this:

```
Users::where('permission', function($q)
{
    $q->from('users')
      ->select('permission')
      ->where('id', '=', 1);

})->where('id', '!=', 1);
```

Comment: This is great, just one question, with the ->from('users') sub query, anyway to specify this with the model instance rather than table name?

Comment: hmm...you can do like $q->from((new App\Models\Users)->getTable()) if you don't want to hard code it